# Footer gets cut off?

Tags: html, css

I'm having some issues with parts of the footer on my website getting cut of on different browsers.

On my website here http://reportalert.info/index-test.php, the twitter, rss and share icons get cut off and move around slightly when on different browsers. I've tried changing the background position and padding of each of the icons but I can't seem to get it to work across different browsers. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Here is the code that I have for the footer:

```
#footer 
{
    clear: both;
    font-family: "Droid Serif";
    margin:10px 0;
    padding-bottom:60px;
    width:100%;
    height:10px;
    text-align:left;
    font-size:80%;
    color:#444;
}
a.ftwitter
{
    background:url(http://reportalert.info/images/nra/ra-share.png/images/nra/ra-twitter.png) left no-repeat;
    background-position:0 -22.5px;
    padding:3px 55px;
}
a.ftwitter:hover
{
    background-position:0 0;
    padding:4px 55px;
}
a.frssfeed
{
    background:url(http://reportalert.info/images/nra/ra-share.png/images/nra/ra-feed.png) left no-repeat;
    background-position:0 -26.5px;
    padding:5px 55px;
}
a.frssfeed:hover
{
    background-position:0 0;
    padding:6px 55px;
}    
a.fshare
{
    background:url(http://reportalert.info/images/nra/ra-share.png) left no-repeat;
    background-position:0 -22.5px;
    padding:3px 60px;
}
a.fshare:hover
{
    background-position:0 0;
    padding:4px 60px;
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Have you done a CSS reset? eg: * {padding: 0px; margin: 0px}. Browsers give there own default padding and margins to some elements so the above resets it all to 0

Comment: It seems to me like you have a div that wraps your entire site and that this div has a value of padding that overlaps the icons in the footer.

Comment: Try applying the same padding values to `:hover`.

Answer (score 3):

Padding works differently in every browser, that's why your icons gets cut off in Chrome.

I would use a specific width and height instead.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of padding, try using width and height. And add a `display: inline-block`. Here for example:

```
a.ftwitter 
{
    display: inline-block; 
    background:url(http://reportalert.info/images/nra/ra-share.png/images/nra/ra-twitter.png) left no-repeat;
    background-position:0 -22.5px;
    width: 110px;
    height: 22px;
}
```

Comment: I tried that but it disappears and only shows up when you hover over it.

Comment: You forgot to put a minus. background-position:0 -22.5px;

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help. Apply this to your icons:

```
position:relative;
z-index:99;
```

Comment: No that won't help and isn't even remotely related to the issue at hand.

Answer (score 0):

The icons that get cut off are all empty `a` elements. Because it's an `inline` flow element, that means it collapses to default text height - 20 pixels in the font you use, while the Twitter icon is 22, hence causing 2 pixels to be cut off.

Set the anchors to `display:inline-block`, or another block layout style fitting in your layout, and the correct height which is then allowed, and it's solved.